# Why functions defined in the same file as main can not be called from other files in the program?

Tags: c, program-entry-point

At a rainy weekend, I was reading K. N. King's **C Programming: A Modern Approach**.

And at page 359, it says that “*It is possible that there are other functions in the same file as main, so long as they are not called from other files in the program.*”

I do not know the reason and I try it like this:

```
// a.h 
int sum(void);
int sub(void);

// a.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"

int a = 0;
int b = 1;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
printf("sum = %d,\nsub = %d,\ndbl= %d\n", sum(), sub(), dbl() );
return 0;
}

int sum()
{
return ( a + b );
}

int sub()
{
return ( a - b );
}




// b.h
int dbl(void);

// b.c
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"
int dbl()
{
return ( sum() + sub() );
}
```

Then I compile it with

> gcc -a.exe a.c b.c

at cygwin. Then run a.exe as

> ./a.exe

Every thing goes well with the output "sum = 1, sub = -1, dbl = 0". So, who gets wrong, Mr K. N. King, or I ?

Comment: I don't have the book, but the statement looks like coding rule for preventing them from writeng dirty code which compiler accepts. Isn't the book telling the reason for the statement after or before that?

Comment: What you're trying to ask? I'm not very clear with the question.

Comment: You can call functions from other files, cause you have added `#include "b.h"` in a.c and `#include "a.h"` in b.c file. Try without including these. You won't get these.

Answer (score 2):

The cited part is program design advise.

There is nothing in the C language preventing you from putting a function definition anywhere in any linked file, as long as a function declaration is visible to the caller.

But it is very bad practice to have specific files call functions in what should be the top level of the application design. The key to good program design is to write autonomous code modules that only does their designated task and knows as little about the rest of the program as possible.

Having various parts of the application call other, non-related parts is sloppy, messy and leads to *tight coupling*. Apart from the program turning out a mess to read and maintain, tight coupling also means that bugs will escalate all over the program. Meaning that when you write a bug in one module, you will break completely non-related parts of the program.

To prevent such things, functions located in `main` should only be helper functions called by `main` itself, if such functions are needed. They should be declared as `static` functions to block other parts of the program from getting access to them.

Answer (score 0):

In "a.h" include the following line:

```
extern int a;
extern int b;
```

Then retry your code and check the output.